# Iterating through a list of names to find specific keyword

Tags: python, pandas, list, iteration

So for this question. I have this column:

[Column of product names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgBbI.png)
I need to create a function where it takes in a keyword and returns all products with that word in the name. For this particular question the keyword is "Wheat". My function is below:

```
def find_word(keyword):
    word = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if keyword in df['name'][i]:
            word.append(df['name'][i])
    return word
find_word("Wheat")
```

And this is what is returned:

['Cream of Wheat (Quick)',
 'Crispy Wheat & Raisins',
 'Frosted Mini-Wheat',
 'Nutri-grain Wheat',
 'Puffed Wheat',
 'Shredded Wheat',
 "Shredded Wheat'n'Bran",
 'Shredded Wheat spoon size',
 'Strawberry Fruit Wheats',
 'Wheat Chex',
 'Wheaties',
 'Wheaties Honey Gold']

As you can see the last 2 as well as the 3rd to last do not belong. Am not sure how to structure the function to look for those cases.

Comment: Why don't the last 3 belong?  They all have "Wheat" in them.

Comment: Are you looking to only match when "Wheat" is a word on its own? Also I don't know the context, but it seems like it might be preferable to pass your dataframe as an argument to the function to make your function more versatile.

Comment: provide "Wheat " into your function like: find_word("Wheat "), notice use space after Wheat

Comment: @Samwise they do have Wheat in them but I need just the term on its own. Not the term within a word

Comment: @ncica, I did try that. The issue is it would neglect the "-Wheat" option which is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for can be achieved by the following using [re](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) module:

```py
import re

def find_word(keyword):
    word = []

    # create a regular expression pattern that would "exactly" match the keyword
    # \b represents Word boundary
    p = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(keyword))

    for i in range(len(df)):
        # use the pattern to search the name
        if p.search(df['name'][i]):
            word.append(df['name'][i])
    return word

find_word("Wheat")
```

```py
['Cream of Wheat (Quick)', 'Crispy Wheat & Raisins', 'Frosted Mini-Wheat', 
 'Nutri-grain Wheat', 'Puffed Wheat', 'Shredded Wheat', 
 "Shredded Wheat'n'Bran", 'Shredded Wheat spoon size', 'Wheat Chex']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
df[df["name"].str.contains(r'(?:\s|^)Wheat(?:\s|$)')]["name"]
```